# How can I get a reader method based on a json property name using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given the following jackson annotated class :

```
public class AClass {

   @JsonProperty("propertyName")
   private String anyProperty

   public String getAnyProperty() {
   ...
   }

...
}
```

or a mixin configuration:

```
public class AClass {

   private String anyProperty

   public String getAnyProperty() {
   ...
   }

...
}

public interface AClassMixin {

   @JsonProperty(value = "propertyName")
  String getAnyProperty();
}
```

How can I get the json property "propertyName' reader method using jackson?

I need something like that:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   Method method = mapper.getReaderMethodForProperty("propertyName", Aclass.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a [`JavaType`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType.html) for your bean class

```
JavaType target = objectMapper.constructType(AClass.class);
```

then use the `ObjectMapper`'s [`DeserializationConfig`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationConfig.html) to introspect it. This will give you a [`BeanDescription`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanDescription.html).

```
BeanDescription beanDescription = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().introspect(target)
```

You can use that to get a list of its [`BeanPropertyDefinition`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/BeanPropertyDefinition.html) instances.

```
List<BeanPropertyDefinition> beanPropertyDefinitions = beanDescription.findProperties();
```

Each `BeanPropertyDefinition` has methods to retrieve getters and setters (and other things) as [`AnnotatedMember`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedMember.html) values from which you can retrieve the [`Member`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html?is-external=true) (you'll need to cast to `Method`).

```
for (BeanPropertyDefinition bpd : beanPropertyDefinitions) {
    AnnotatedMember annotatedMember = bpd.getAccessor();
    Member member = annotatedMember.getMember();
    if (member instanceof Method) {
        Method getterMethod = (Method) member;
        System.out.println(getterMethod.getName());
    }
}
```